# Modal undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a modal promp when my page opens, i want it to show an image. For some reason it keeps telling me that the image is undefined, when i use it with onlick function it shows ok. Im using a modify version of a W3School script. Any ideas?  Thanks in advance! Code:

```
          HTML:                  
                            <img id="myImg" src="http://192.185.4.115/~hitclubar/images/prueba.png" alt="" width="300" height="200" style="display:none;">

                             <!--The Modal --> 
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                              <a href="http://facebook.com/Hitclubar">   Click Evento Facebook </a>
                              <span class="close">×</span>
                              <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                              <div id="caption"></div>
                            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


$(function(){ 
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = document.getElementById('myImg');
modalImg.alt = "HOLA";
captionText.innerHTML = "HOLA";
});


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS:

```
#myImg {
                        border-radius: 5px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        transition: 0.3s;
                }

                #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

                /* The Modal (background) */
                .modal {
                        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 100%; /* Full width */
                        height: 100%; /* Full height */
                        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
                 }

                 /* Modal Content (image) */
                 .modal-content {
                        margin: auto;
                        display: block;
                        width: 80%;
                        max-width: 700px;
                 }

                 /* Caption of Modal Image */
                 #caption {
                        margin: auto;
                        display: block;
                        width: 80%;
                        max-width: 700px;
                        text-align: center;
                        color: #ccc;
                        padding: 10px 0;
                        height: 170px;
                  }

                  /* Add Animation */
                  .modal-content, #caption {
                        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
                        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
                        animation-name: zoom;
                        animation-duration: 0.6s;
                  }

                  @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
                        from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
                        to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
                  }

                  @keyframes zoom {
                        from {transform:scale(0)}
                        to {transform:scale(1)}
                  }

                  /* The Close Button */
                  .close {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 15px;
                        right: 35px;
                        color: #f1f1f1;
                        font-size: 40px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        transition: 0.3s;
                  }

                  .close:hover,
                  .close:focus {
                        color: #bbb;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        cursor: pointer;
                  }

                  /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
                  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
                 .modal-content {
                        width: 100%;
                        }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You placed

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
```

at the beginning of the script. That way the script tries to get hold of the modal early during page load (which fails as it does not exist yet).

Try it this way:

```
$(function() {
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption"); 

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = document.getElementById('myImg');
    modalImg.alt = "HOLA";
    captionText.innerHTML = "HOLA";
});
```

Now the modal gets referenced when the page has fully loaded the html and it should work.